# How to skip the array item which not starting the letter of 'b'

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array and loop like this:

```
<?php 
  $letters = array("a", "b", "aa", "c", "bb", "bcb");
  foreach( $letters as $letter ){
    echo "$letter <br />";
  }
?>
```

I'm getting all value from here.

But I just need that value whose first letter is 'B'.
How can I get it please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select first char of `$letter` by suing `substr`, then compare by `b`.

**Note**: *change case to lower for support `b` and `B`*

```
$letters = array("a", "b", "aa", "c", "bb", "bcb");
foreach ($letters as $letter)
{
    if (strtolower(substr($letter, 0, 1)) != 'b')
    {
        continue;
    }

    echo "$letter <br />";
}
```

Comment: But I need item starting with b

Comment: if (strtolower(substr($letter, 0, 1)) == 'b')

Comment: @SABappy Based on the title of question `skip the array item which not starting the letter of 'b'` it should be `!= 'b'`, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Lessmore's answer, but reducing a few things.

You don't need to do `substr()` for 1 character, you can just use the idea of using a string as an array and use `$letter[0]`.

I've also changed the condition so that it checks `===` b, so this saves having a continue and just does the processing in the `if` instead.

```
$letters = array("a", "b", "aa", "c", "bb", "bcb");
foreach ($letters as $letter)
{
    if (strtolower($letter[0]) === 'b')
    {
         echo "$letter <br />";
    }
   
}
```